# How to pass a dynamic value to another view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

anybody can teach me how to set default value in VIEW page?
the thing I want is something like :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MemAd , value="M")
```

and

How can I pass dynamic value to another view page by using session?

Comment: A great place to start is http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 3):

You do this in the controller action rendering this view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    MyViewModel model = ...
    model.MemAd = "M";
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the corresponding view:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MemAd)
```

will generate:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MemAd" id="MemAd" value="M" />
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: i want to create a register page , but only some field have default value and be hidden

Comment: So what's the problem with using a view model and setting their default values in the controller?

Comment: for viewing and insert into database... Or you can teach me another way for solve it?>

Comment: Darin Dimitrov , can you show me how to insert data into database??
dropdownlist , textbox ,hidden field , radio and checkbox ..